# Remove radio buttons from dropdown from Google Chrome Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I want to remove the Radio Buttons from the Drop Down on mobile devices.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The problem is I cannot see them when I test on desktop browsers using developer tools.
It only recreates on an actual phone. Here in Google Chrome browser.
So I cannot hide them as I don't know the selectors.

How can I acheive this with Css.
Thanks

Comment: you can transform desktop chrome into mobile device view in inspect element using `Ctrl+Shift+M` or clicking `Toggle Device Toolbar`

Comment: @Usama Yes, As I mentioned in the question I know how to check for responsive through dev tools. But these radio buttons only appear on actual mobile device

Comment: try changing dimensions on chrome, I suppose you have tried this as well... these techniques may help https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/, [How to Inspect Websites on Mobile Devices](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/google-chrome-how-to-inspect-websites-on-mobile-devices-804677f863ce)